# SDL2.0 texture color becomes in pick

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

I am tring to render the frame that have received from ffmpeg into texture with the help of SDL_UpdateYUVTexture.

The interesting part is that it get rendered in HTC, Motorola properly, but in SAMSUNG GALAXY S3, the whole image is in pink color.

what could be an issue ?

the similar report can be seen : http://openxcom.org/forum/index.php?topic=1864.60

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this Issue is to Change the setting in the developers option:

Settings -> More -> Developers Option -> "Check " disable Hardware Overlays.

Good Luck.